# how can I run a websocket server. I'm using WampServer 2.1

Tags: php, html, wamp, wampserver, phpwebsocket

it says it clearly in the heading. I want a way to **run a websocket server** in apache server that comes with Wamp 2.1

### update

check this page http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/ look at step 9 where it describes how to run a websocket server. that's for XAMPP. I want to do it in WAMP. Sorry if it was unclear.

---

### udate 2

[image: cmd on win 7]

I tried to run it as in the photo but ,as you see, I'm doing that wrong. sorry guys I'm not good at command lines. could you please show me the exact way to run the websocket-server

---

### update 3

[image: cmd accessing php.exe]

another trial and nothing happened.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't say it very clearly. What do you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone actually knows what a "php-websocket file" actually is... and as for connecting it, tried sticky tape?

Comment: Funny @JamesButler :P I hope it's clear now. thanks.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi That makes things a little clearer now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is a shell/terminal/command line (whatever your operating system of choice calls it) in which you type:

```
php -q /path/to/your/script.php
```

Where `php` is the path to the PHP executable followed by the option `-q` followed by the path to your script. This doesn't really depend on (X/W/M)AMP much.

Comment: Search for where php.exe is installed on your system, use that path.

Comment: No, call it like `C:\wamp\...\php.exe -q C:\...\startDaemon.php`.

Answer (score 4):

I have found some idea to make WAMP work with the tutorial.
You need to edit the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\php.ini and add a line **extension=php_sockets.dll** and then call **php -q C:\wamp\www\websocket\server\startDaemon.php** in cmd and the websocket will work.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>php -q C:\wamp\www\websocket\server\startDaemon.php
2012-10-30 14:30:35 System: Socket Resource id #7 created.
2012-10-30 14:30:35 System: Socket bound to localhost:8000.
2012-10-30 14:30:35 System: Start listening on Socket.
2012-10-30 14:31:04 WebSocket: Resource id #8 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:31:04 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:31:04 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:04 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:04 WebSocket: Resource id #8 disconnected!
2012-10-30 14:31:34 WebSocket: Resource id #9 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:31:34 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:31:34 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:34 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:34 WebSocket: Resource id #9 disconnected!
2012-10-30 14:31:37 WebSocket: Resource id #10 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:31:37 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:31:37 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:37 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:31:37 WebSocket: Resource id #10 disconnected!
2012-10-30 14:32:23 WebSocket: Resource id #11 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:32:23 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:32:23 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:32:23 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:32:23 WebSocket: Resource id #11 disconnected!
2012-10-30 14:36:02 WebSocket: Resource id #12 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:36:02 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:36:02 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:02 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:07 WebSocket: Resource id #13 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:36:07 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:36:07 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:07 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:10 WebSocket: Resource id #14 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:36:10 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:36:10 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:10 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:31 WebSocket: Resource id #15 CONNECTED!
2012-10-30 14:36:31 WebSocket: Requesting handshake...
2012-10-30 14:36:31 WebSocket: Handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:31 WebSocket: Done handshaking...
2012-10-30 14:36:31 WebSocket: Resource id #15 disconnected!
```

***P/S: I think there is another way without edit php.ini manually. Click on WAMP Icon PHP -> PHP Extensions -> PHP Socket and Tick it. I guess it will work too.***